# O que é o attr_accessor no Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou aprendendo [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) e no conteúdo que estou estudando não consegui entender bem o que é o `attr_accessor` e como ele funciona.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O `attr_accessor` é um "atalho" que cria métodos de leitura, escrita e variável de instância em uma classe.

http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor

Ex.:

Suponha que vc tenha uma classe `Carro` quisesse acessar uma propriedade `cor`:

```
class Carro
end

carro = Carro.new
carro.cor # => NoMethodError: undefined method `cor'
carro.cor = 'azul' # => NoMethodError: private method `cor='
```

Você poderia implementar desta forma:

```
class Carro
   @cor=nil

   def cor
      @cor
   end

   def cor=(value)
     @cor = value
   end

end
```

Desta forma,

```
carro = Carro.new
carro.cor = 'azul'
carro.cor # => "azul"
```

Usando `attr_accessor`, esse código é criado para você, a classe ficaria assim:

```
class Carro
   attr_accessor :cor
end
```

e a funcionalidade é a mesma.

Comment: Para quem está acostumado com outras linguagens POO, Sim, attr_accessor não é nada mais do que um getter / setter para um objeto no Ruby! https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/11/attr_accessor/